# numpy dot on 1D and 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dot-product

I am trying to understand what happens in the following python code:

```
import numpy as np

numberList1 = [1,2,3]
numberList2 = [[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

result = np.dot(numberList2, numberList1)

# Converting iterator to set
resultSet = set(result)
print(resultSet)
```

Output:

> {32, 50}

I can see that it is multiplying each element in `numberList1` by the element in the same position in each array within `numberList2` - so `{1*4 + 2*5 + 3*6 = 32},{1*7+2*8+3*9 = 50}`.

But, if I change the arrays to:

```
numberList1 = [1,1,1]
numberList2 = [[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
```

Then the output I see is

> {9, 6}

Which is the wrong way around...

and, if I change it to:

```
numberList1 = [1,1,1]
numberList2 = [[2,2,2],[2,2,2]]
```

Then the output I see is just

> {6}

From the documentation:

> If a is an N-D array and b is a 1-D array, it is a sum product over the last axis of a and b.

I am not enough of a mathematician to understand quite what this is telling me; or why the order of the outputs swaps around sometimes.

Comment: a `set` is an unordered data type. did you mean to create a tuple? or just leave it as `np.array` (the result of `dot` is not an iterator...) and not put it in a different data type?

Comment: of course! Thank you

Comment: so what does it mean by "the last axis of a and b" in the docs?

Comment: https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/numpy-axes-explained/ may help.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to add an answer if you want the credit; otherwise I'll do it.

Comment: ok, did that. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) is an unordered data type - and it will remove your duplicates. [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html#numpy.dot) does not return an iterator (as mentioned in your code) but an [`np.ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html#numpy.ndarray) which will be in the order you expect:

```
import numpy as np

numberList1 = [1, 2, 3]
numberList2 = [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

result = np.dot(numberList2, numberList1)
# [32 50]
# <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

# numberList1 = [1, 1, 1]
# numberList2 = [[2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
# -> [6 9]
```